# Uploading file in HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was learning hadoop and till now I configured 3 Node cluster
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.1.1 hadoop-namenode
10.0.1.2 hadoop-datanode-2
10.0.1.3 hadoop-datanode-3

My hadoop Namenode directory looks like below

hadoop
bin
data->  ./namenode   ./datanode
etc
logs
sbin
--
--

As I learned that when we upload a large file in the cluster in divide the file into blocks, I want to upload a 1Gig file in my cluster and want to see how it is being stored in datanode.

Can anyone help me with the commands to upload file and see where these blocks are being stored.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if you have Hadoop tools in your path, if not - I recommend integrate them into it.

One of the possible ways of uploading a file to HDFS:`hadoop fs -put /path/to/localfile /path/in/hdfs`

I would suggest you read the documentation and get familiar with high-level commands first as it will save you time
[Hadoop Documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)

Start with "dfs" command, as this one of the most often used commands

Comment: I'm glad that I was helpful. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider  [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.